# How is the axle held in at the transmission ('88 Accord)?

Tags: honda, accord, axle, cv-joint, cv-boot

I'm attempting to change a CV boot on my 1988 Accord. To do this I must remove the axle.

I've remove the wheel, hub and suspension and so have the outer-side of the axle exposed.

But how do I remove the inner side of the axle (the part that connects to the transmission)? I can't find any info on this. Can I just pull it out?

Comment: Just a note, but if you're removing the axle to change the boot, it's often a lot easier (and not much more expensive) to just replace the axle.

Comment: @PeteCon yeah I've heard that. Unfortunately, these were not a too common car here in Australia so I can't find any that aren't over $100 in shipping alone. Luckily they still stock the boots here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look to the very right in this image:

[image: From Rockauto.com]

You'll see a snap ring. This holds the end of the axle in the transmission. To get it out, you need to wedge something like a long flat tip screwdriver or pry bar in between the transmission case and axle, and pop it free. It will take a little bit of finagling, but it will pop out. Don't pull on the axle shaft itself, as you risk pulling the CV joint apart.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Paulster2. I imagine to reinstall you'd just push it back in until it clicks?

Comment: @MeltingDog - Yes. It can be a little tricky sometimes. Don't be afraid to use a little force (ie: pressure ... don't hammer on it with anything ... wouldn't be good).